# Highcharts : Working with JSON objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and  have a requirement to plot charts, where the JSON data which i have is of below structure:

```
{ "RigName": "RIG-101", TimeFrame: "2014", "Value": 578, "Category": "Hazard Hunt" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-101", TimeFrame: "2015", "Value": 555, "Category": "Hazard Hunt" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-102", TimeFrame: "2014", "Value": 350, "Category": "Hazard Hunt" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-103", TimeFrame: "2014", "Value": 120, "Category": "Hazard Hunt" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-103", TimeFrame: "2015", "Value": 460, "Category": "Hazard Hunt" },
      { "RigName": "RIG-101", TimeFrame: "2015", "Value": 160, "Category": "TRIC" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-102", TimeFrame: "2014", "Value": 210, "Category": "TRIC" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-102", TimeFrame: "2015", "Value": 152, "Category": "TRIC" },
     { "RigName": "RIG-101", TimeFrame: "2014", "Value": 420, "Category": "Kilometers" },
      { "RigName": "RIG-101", TimeFrame: "2015", "Value": 489, "Category": "Kilometers" },
      { "RigName": "RIG-102", TimeFrame: "2014", "Value": 450, "Category": "Kilometers" },
      { "RigName": "RIG-102", TimeFrame: "2015", "Value": 555, "Category": "Kilometers" },
```

I want my graph to look like this: (p.s: below picture is just an example how the end result would look like, and it is not as per above data.)
[image]

Which is it is grouped by "TimeFrame", "RigName" as x-axis and "Values" as y-axis for a selected "Category" (say for example "Hazard Hunt"; we need to first filter JSON data where "category"="Hazard Hut" and use.).

What is the best way i can initialize Highcharts and use this JSON data as datasource, with or without processing it?

thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not possible to use this JSON format directly with Highcharts without processing. You should set series as your grouping is, change "RigName" to name or just use it to establish categories for xAxis, set x coordinates based on categories, change "Values" to "y". Data needs to be parsed to match one of required Highcharts data format - the format you are using is not supported.

Comment: @KacperMadej thank you. I have tried by giving data as an array by processing my original data as highchart expects (and it works). But i felt processing is a costly process in my scenario. just wanted to know if there is a way out.